# Manifest-declared BroadcastReceiver not picking up explicit broadcast when app is not running

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get two apps to communicate via broadcasts. The first app sends a broadcast using code like the following:

```
Intent outIntent = new Intent("org.example.WHATEVER");
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> receivers = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(outIntent, 0);
if (receivers != null)
    for (ResolveInfo receiver : receivers) {
        Log.d("Sender", String.format("Polling %s", receiver.activityInfo.packageName));
        outIntent = new Intent("org.example.WHATEVER");
        outIntent.setPackage(receiver.activityInfo.packageName);
        sendBroadcast(outIntent);
    }
```

The receiving end registers a `BroadcastReceiver` in its manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="org.example.receiverapp.WhateverReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.example.WHATEVER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `onReceive()` method writes a log entry when invoked.

When the receiving app is running (i.e. I’ve had its main activity on screen, then navigated away from it), it processes the broadcast. However, if the receiver app is not running (which I ensure by long-pressing Back, having activated “Long-press Back to kill app” in Developer Settings), it is not woken up by the broadcast.

I am deliberately setting a package name for the intent, to avoid issues with [manifest-declared receivers no longer receiving implicit broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) from Android 8 onwards. Besides, I am running Android 7, with both apps targeting API 23, thus any restrictions in Android 8 should not matter in this setup anyway.

I’ve come across a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766788/android-broadcastreceiver-not-triggering-when-app-is-not-running#comment80856311_41766788) whose author suggests that certain flavors of Android may not wake applications for broadcasts, which seems to be what I am experiencing here (running LineageOS 14.1)—though that comment isn’t very specific and I haven’t found anything else backing this claim.

Is this what is happening here? If so, how can I ensure the receiver app is woken up by the broadcast (at least if it is directed)? If not, what’s wrong here?

Comment: Rather than `setPackage()`, [try `setComponent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName)) and see if that helps. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html) and the code snippet at the bottom. Also, bear in mind that the problem may be with what `WhateverReceiver` is doing (e.g., if you are trying to start a service, that won't work unless you use `startForegroundService()` and make the service be foreground when it starts).

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed, this does the trick. Why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make an explicit `Intent`, I usually [use `setComponent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName)), as it is guaranteed to work (as much as anything is):

```
Intent outIntent = new Intent("org.example.WHATEVER");
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> receivers = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(outIntent, 0);
if (receivers != null)
    for (ResolveInfo receiver : receivers) {
        Log.d("Sender", String.format("Polling %s/%s",
                receiver.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                receiver.activityInfo.name));
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                receiver.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                receiver.activityInfo.name);
        outIntent = new Intent("org.example.WHATEVER");
        outIntent.setComponent(cn);
        sendBroadcast(outIntent);
    }
```

In some cases, `setPackage()` makes an `Intent` "explicit enough" to satisfy some Android criterion. Apparently in this case, it does not. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Do you know why setPackage() is not working here ?

Comment: @JeganBabu: No, sorry.